# Execute one method depending execution of another method in android

Tags: android

I have written two methods A & B. The method A has a countdown timer and it logs input over 4 minutes.
I want method B to be executed after method A runs for over 4 minutes.

What are the ways of making this possible.

I have tried to use Asynctask to no avail.

Help is appreciated

Comment: ... try using a CountDownTimer.

Comment: I am already using that...

Comment: Then you're using it the wrong way.

Comment: can you post your code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Asynctask  you start new  process when old process completed..

Like

In process A

```
  protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

   task.execute("your url");// start new Asynctask of Process B
  }
```